# unwarp square faces to non square image texture

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have a non square texture ( 3000 x 1000 pixels). I want to unwarp a basic cube. Since it's cube, each face is a square ( all side has same length) or let say the aspect ratio between width and height of the face is 1:1.

If select all face then unwarp (using smart uv project) , the result in the uv editor is not square. all faces are stretched.

How can i do 'smart uv project' for all the faces and get the proper aspect ratio for each faces ?

So far i can get the proper ratio by using standard 'unwarp' for each face and have to manually arrange them across the texture one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Smart UV project* can't handle non-uniform textures.
The standard *UV > Unwrap* works just fine, if you check ✓*Correct Aspect*.

<sup>If you insist on Smart UV Project, scale the resulting UV map to 1/3 width</sup>

[image]